# WS2012R2: Symlink from a network share to another network share?

Tags: windows, networking, server, share, symlink

I have a question according to creating symlinks on network share which link to another network share.

The Windows clients in our company have a network drive mapped on J:\

the UNC path is \\DataServer01\network

previously, there was some kind of a symlink in the network directory called "import" (so the UNC path was \\DataServer01\network\import), which was linking so \\ERPServer01\share\import.

So the users could go to their mapped network drive on J and put a excel file into J:\import - so the excel file was put to \\ERPServer01\share\import in reality.

Accidentaly, the symlink was deleted by another admin. Now I was trying to recreate the symlink using 
**mklink /d import \\ERPServer01\share\import**
And so far the symlink was created, and you could access it from the DataServer01. But - you can't access that symlink from the network drive J:\. If you try this, you receive the error that the symbolic link cannot be accessed. I googled a lot and the reasons why this concept couldn't work (links are resolved relatively by clients) was quite plausible.
The thing is, my predecessor got it to work somehow, he somehow managed to create a proper "symlink" or hard link or something similar. How the hell did he managed to get it to work? Unfortunately I can't ask him.
There is also no DFS in use. It must have beed some other method.
I have to recreate it exactly how it was, because I don't want to explain to 300 users why they have to put their excel sheets in another directory now. And I don't want to map another network drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can enable symlink remote-to-remote evaluation via either group policy or in the registry of individual systems in "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem".

Comment: Thank you, symlinkevaluation was the proper term for the solution. The Syntax was "fsutil behavior set symlinkevaluation R2R:1" and pushed over GPO afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it wasn't a symlink before (checked your backup?). Alternatively, you can create a "magic" Explorer folder:

1. create an empty source folder
2. inside the source folder, create an Explorer link to the target folder named `target`
3. inside the source folder, create a `desktop.ini` text file with the contents

   ```
   [.ShellClassInfo]
   CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}
   ```
4. flag `desktop.ini` as *System* and *Hidden*
5. flag source folder as *System*

An Explorer magic link folder looks similar to a symlink but only works with Windows Explorer whereas a symlink works with (nearly) everything, once activated through GPO.